# JAVA linking ID to name from other table

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview

I got a tableview with a tablecolumn ("ID").

How can i link the ID to show the value?
For example: ID 90 has to be "Shop" and ID 91 has to be "Wallmart"..

I'm using 2 tables:

Person(id, personName, personShopID)

Items(id, shopName)

PersonShopID links to ITEMS id and i have to show the shopName instead of the ID..

Note: I'm using JavaFX and i'm getting data from mysql database and i'm using `tcShopName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("personShopID"));`

kind regards !

```
 package databag;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import vivesgoal.controller.CustomDate;

/**
 *
 * @author Lowie Menu
 */
public class PersoonBag {
    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private String voornaam;
    private Date geboortedatum;
    private String opmerking;
    private boolean isTrainer;
   private int ploeg_id;

    public PersoonBag(int id, String naam, String voornaam, Date geboortedatum, String opmerking,boolean isTrainer, int ploeg_id){
       this.id=id;
       this.naam=naam;
       this.voornaam=voornaam;
       this.geboortedatum=geboortedatum;
       this.opmerking=opmerking;
       this.isTrainer=isTrainer;
       this.ploeg_id=ploeg_id;
}

    public PersoonBag()
    {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public String getVoornaam() {
        return voornaam;
    }

    public Date getGeboortedatum() {
        return geboortedatum;
    }

    public String getGeboortedatumAlter(){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String datum = df.format(geboortedatum);
        return datum;
    }

    public CustomDate getMyDate(){
        return new CustomDate(geboortedatum.getTime());
    }

    public java.util.Date getGeboortedatumUtil(){
        return geboortedatum;
    }

    public String getOpmerking() {
        return opmerking;
    }

    public boolean isIsTrainer() {
        return isTrainer;
    }

    public int getPloeg_id() {
        return ploeg_id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNaam(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    public void setVoornaam(String voornaam) {
        this.voornaam = voornaam;
    }

    public void setGeboortedatum(Date geboortedatum) {
        this.geboortedatum =geboortedatum;
    }

    public void setOpmerking(String opmerking) {
        this.opmerking = opmerking;
    }

    public void setIsTrainer(boolean isTrainer) {
        this.isTrainer = isTrainer;
    }

    public void setPloeg_id(int ploeg_id) {
        this.ploeg_id = ploeg_id;
    }


}
```

and class Team (dutch ploeg)

```
package databag;
/**
 *
 * @author Lowie Menu
 */
public class PloegBag {
    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private String niveau;
  private int trainer_id;

    public PloegBag(int id, String naam, String niveau, int trainer_id){
        this.id = id;
        this.naam = naam;
        this.niveau = niveau;
       this.trainer_id = trainer_id;
    }

    public PloegBag(){
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNaam(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    public void setNiveau(String niveau) {
        this.niveau = niveau;
    }

    public void setTrainer_id(int trainer_id){
        this.trainer_id=trainer_id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public String getNiveau() {
        return niveau;
    }

    public int getTrainer_id(){
        return trainer_id;
    }

}
```

Note: i'm trying to link ploeg_id from PersoonBag to the name of PloegBag(ploegnaam).

**This sql code gets me the name of the club matching the id**

```
select * from persoon AS p INNER JOIN ploeg AS ploeg ON p.ploeg_id =ploeg.id where ploeg.naam=?"
```

**Update: no value in ploeg.naam? maybe issue here**

p

```
ublic ArrayList<PersoonBag> zoekAlleSpelers() throws DBException, ApplicationException {

        ArrayList<PersoonBag> pb = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();) {

            try(PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select * from persoon inner join ploeg where persoon.ploeg_id = ploeg.id");) {
            // execute voert elke sql-statement uit, executeQuery enkel de eenvoudige
            stmt.execute();
            // result opvragen (en automatisch sluiten)
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet()) {

                    // van alle rekennigen uit de database,
               // RekeningBag-objecten maken en in een RekeningVector steken
               while (rs.next()) {
                  PersoonBag p = new PersoonBag();
                  PloegBag ploeg = new PloegBag();
                 // ploeg.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                  ploeg.setNaam(rs.getString("naam"));



                  p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                  p.setNaam(rs.getString("naam"));
                  p.setVoornaam(rs.getString("voornaam"));                 
                  p.setGeboortedatum(rs.getDate("geboortedatum"));
                  p.setOpmerking(rs.getString("opmerking"));
                  p.setIsTrainer(rs.getBoolean("isTrainer"));
                  p.setPloeg_id(ploeg);

                  pb.add(p);

               }
               return pb;
            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
               throw new DBException(
                  "SQL-exception in zoekAlleRekeningen - resultset");
            }
         } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            throw new DBException(
               "SQL-exception in zoekAlleRekeningen - statement");
         }
      } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
         throw new DBException(
            "SQL-exception in zoekAlleRekeningen - connection");
      }
   }
```

**Still have'nt found the issue.. this is function to store the data from the sql query in the table note: this works only ploegname isn't showing**

```
       PersoonDB pdb = new PersoonDB();
    ArrayList<PersoonBag> persoonbag = new ArrayList<>();   

    try {
        ArrayList<PersoonBag> spelersLijst = pdb.zoekAlleSpelers();
        for (PersoonBag r : spelersLijst) {
           PersoonBag speler = new PersoonBag(r.getId(),r.getNaam(), r.getVoornaam(),r.getMyDate(),r.getOpmerking(), r.isIsTrainer(),r.getPloeg_id());
           persoonbag.add(speler);
        }

        ObservableList<PersoonBag> spelers = FXCollections.observableArrayList(persoonbag);
        taSpelers.setItems(spelers);
```

**Cell items:**

```
 @FXML
    private TableView<PersoonBag> taSpelers;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn tcFamilienaam;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn tcVoornaam;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn tcOpmerking;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PersoonBag, CustomDate> tcGeboortedatum;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PersoonBag, PloegBag> tcPloeg;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {   
    tcFamilienaam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("naam"));
    tcVoornaam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("voornaam"));
    tcGeboortedatum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PersoonBag, CustomDate>("geboortedatum"));
    tcOpmerking.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("opmerking"));
    tcPloeg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ploeg"));    
    tcPloeg.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<PersoonBag, PloegBag>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(PloegBag ploeg, boolean empty) {
            if (empty || ploeg ==null){
                setText("");
            } else{
                setText(ploeg.getNaam());
            }
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE!!! i'm almost there! It's getting the 'naam' data from persoon instead of 'naam' from ploeg!**

issue:

```
 while (rs.next()) {

             PloegBag ploeg = new PloegBag();
             ploeg.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
           ploeg.setNaam(rs.getString("naam"));

           PersoonBag p = new PersoonBag();  
              p.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
              p.setNaam(rs.getString("naam"));
              p.setVoornaam(rs.getString("voornaam"));                 
              p.setGeboortedatum(rs.getDate("geboortedatum"));
              p.setOpmerking(rs.getString("opmerking"));
              p.setIsTrainer(rs.getBoolean("isTrainer"));
              p.setPloeg(ploeg);

              pb.add(p);

           }
```

**when i'm putting niveau instead of 'naam' it's get me the correct matching result! now i need the name..!**

Comment: Can you post your `Person` and `Item` class code? Are you able to change their structure if you need to?

Comment: And are you using plain JDBC or JPA?

Comment: @James_D, i am using JDBC i have connection with database also so the connection is up. I will post the class code as an "edit". I used Person and Item as an example.

Comment: it is widely known that sourcecode should be in **english** - for many, many reasons. It hurts my eye trying to read that. If you want your software to be maintainable to any extent you will have to change that

Comment: @specializt, i'm doing this for a school project, after the project this will be useless. Sorry for this

Comment: I don't know why you are copying all the data from one list to another; but is the `ploeg` present in the data when you have loaded it from the database? (Just do `for (PersoonBag r : spelersLijst) System.out.println(r.getPloeg_id();`) If so, the problem is in the UI code. If not, it's in the database code...

Comment: can we use teamviewer to have a better communication? I feel like i'm making a very stupid little mistake .. but i'm overlooking it!

Comment: I used the code and got returned databag.PloegBag@5245972c, so it's loaded I assume? else it would be null

Comment: Correct. So now just show your table column, cell factory, and cell value factory.

Comment: Added them! We'r almost there :D

Comment: @James_D can't seem to find the issue :(

Comment: Does your `PersoonBag` class have a ‘getPloeg()` method?

Comment: Yes. --> i named it ploeg_id
    public PloegBag getPloeg_id() {
        return ploeg_id;
    }

Comment: I just renamed all my ploeg_id in personBag to ploeg like you did , so it's now public PloegBag getPloeg() { return ploeg }

Comment: Can we please use teamviewer as this will solve the issue in no time? thanks for helping me so much!

Comment: @James_D i found it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the id of the linked item, store a reference to the item itself. So your `PersoonBag` class will look like:

```
public class PersoonBag {
    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private String voornaam;
    private Date geboortedatum;
    private String opmerking;
    private boolean isTrainer;
    private PloegBag ploeg;

    public PersoonBag(int id, String naam, String voornaam, Date geboortedatum, String opmerking,boolean isTrainer, PloegBag ploeg){
       this.id=id;
       this.naam=naam;
       this.voornaam=voornaam;
       this.geboortedatum=geboortedatum;
       this.opmerking=opmerking;
       this.isTrainer=isTrainer;
       this.ploeg=ploeg;
    }

    public PersoonBag()
    {
    }

    public PloegBag getPloeg() {
        return ploeg ;
    }

    public void setPloeg(PloegBag ploeg) {
        this.ploeg = ploeg ;
    }

    // other get/set methods ...

}
```

Now you can load everything at once using an inner join in the SQL:

```
String sql = "select * from persoon inner join ploeg where persoon.ploeg_id = ploeg.id";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
List<Persoon> persoonList = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    PloegBag ploeg = new PloegBag();
    // populate ploeg with data from rs...
    PersoonBag persoon = new PersoonBag();
    persoon.setPloeg(ploeg);
    // populate persoon with remaining data from rs...
    persoonList.add(persoon);
}
```

(Obviously you can modify the SQL code, e.g. to retrieve specific items from the database, or just generally to improve it, etc.)

Now your JavaFX code looks like:

```
TableView<PersoonBag> persoonTable = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<PersoonBag, PloegBag> tcPloeg = new TableColumn<>("Ploeg");
tcPloeg.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ploeg"));
// other columns...
```

To get the cells to display the value you need from the `PloegBag`, there are two ways. The "quick and dirty" way is just to define a `toString()` method in the `PloegBag` class:

```
public class PloegBag {

    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return naam ;
    }
}
```

This isn't very satisfactory, though, as you might want to `toString()` method to do something else for other reasons in your application. The "proper" way is to use a cell factory:

```
tcPloeg.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<PersoonBag, PloegBag>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(PloegBag ploeg, boolean empty) {
        if (empty || ploeg == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(ploeg.getNaam());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: I do recommend using the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) (i.e. use `StringProperty`, `ObjectProperty<PloegBag>` etc for the fields, and have getX/setX/xProperty methods) for model classes: I didn't here as you didn't in your original code, but it makes everything in JavaFX work more smoothly if you do

Comment: I will try this out now! Look's to be heading the right direction! thanks for helping me. I'll update you asap

Comment: I just implemented all of the code you suggested, with mixed results, i only see the persons now in the table who hava a ploeg_id..(sql statement). Also the tablecolumn is empty and doesnt display the ploeg.getNaam().

When I do " System.out.println(ploeg.getNaam()) i get null values returned . I feel we are very close!

Comment: I think I know where i'm making a mistake .. i'll edit my post !

Answer (score 0):

1) establish a Connection to your database from your Java-program by using JDBC:

```
private static Connection getDBConnection()  {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?autoReconnect=true&user=myUser&password=myPass");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Error on getDBCOnnection "+e.toString());
    } 
    return connection;
}
```

2) Query your `Items` table in a query like this:

```
SELECT shopName FROM Items WHERE ID = 90
```

Java:

```
public static ResultSet runQuery(String query) {
  if(conn == null){
      conn = getDBConnection();
  }
  Statement stmt;
  ResultSet rs;

  try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    return rs;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e + " " + e.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
}
```

3) Read the result

```
ResultSet rs = runQuery(query);
String result = rs.getString(1);
```

Comment: You're going to run a query for every single cell in the column? Won't that perform prohibitively badly when, for example, the user scrolls through the table?

Comment: depends on your use-case. The above is just a General outline on how to "link an ID to a value" as stated in the question. Of corse you can (and should) fetch more than one ID by using a different query....

Comment: The OP specifies the use case. He/She is displaying the items in a JavaFX `TableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate could do it all for you, including queries... just saying... Although steep learning curve if doing it for the first time... You need to model your container object to have these fields, for example person would have:

```
class Person{
   long id;
   String name;
   String shopName;
   ...
}
```

Then in your data service (provider of data) you would query for that, lets say:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, s.name 
FROM person p, shop s 
WHERE p.shopId = s.shopId;
```

and provide simple rowmapper

```
@Ovrride
public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
  Person person = new Person(rs.getInt("personId"), rs.getString("personName"), rs.getString("shopName"));
  return person;
}
```

You end up with list of Persons, which you can operate on within app. As someone mentioned earlier, you would want to do this, beforehand. Every time you need that list you would hit a local cache, instead of going back to DB. You could set a policy to refresh cache if needed.